# Recommendations for choosing a programming language

Tags: c#, java, c++, python, httpwebrequest

Days ago I created a program in Python to download stuff from the Internet, doing HTTP `POST` and `GET` and parsing `JSON` objects. I noticed some slow performance and I was thinking about writing it from scratch using another language, so I started to write it in C++ to make it faster. Finally I give up, C++ wasn't made for the Internet and it's very difficult to get something working.

I was thinking about giving C# or Java a try, which would you recommend? (I need my program to be fully cross-platform, other programming languages are valid too)

**Edit:** You can check the source code here: http://code.google.com/p/grooveapi/

Comment: Clearly, you won't get any balanced opinion in the religious war between C# and Java. Besides, you forgot to mention excellent interpreted languages, that are undoubtly web-friendly : Groovy, Ruby, ...

Comment: strange, I voted to close but not as "subjective and argumentative" but as "off-topic on StackOverflow.com" which is for programming queries and not other parts of the development process such as selecting the best language to use for a situation.

Comment: @CashCow: Others voted differently, apparently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you need it to be cross-platform:** (i.e. you just write it once and it can run anywhere) Then Java or Python are your only options. This is because any C variant will need compiling specifically for the platform you intend to use it on.

**My suggestion:** Out of the two I would suggest **Python**. I have be educated in Java at University, and have learnt Python myself. Python is the language I turn to for web programming projects (in the form of Django on a larger scale) and the language used at companies I have worked for inside of their web applications.

Comment: Python is nice for web applications, yes, but I want to do a desktop one. Most of computer users aren't used to run python code, and for that it's difficult to share programs written in that language, and as I said before, in some cases it has a slow performance. I think I will finally choose Java, but I will wait for more answers.

Comment: @0x77D Yes then Java would be a good choice, I have a lot of experience coding GUIs in Java by hand and actaully like the process. I have not tried the same in Python, but I don't really want to either.

Comment: @0x77D Both Python and Java requires runtimes that need to be shipped and installed with the software if on Windows. So there is no difference there. On Unix and OS X you already have Python installed. So Python is not a particularily bad choice of desktop software. Also you can bundle Python into exe files.

Answer (score 7):

Rewriting an IO bound application in a different language is unlikely to make any difference in its execution speed.

Answer (score 2):

Before you switch to another language... are you sure the performance problems are due to the language itself? It can very well be possible the problem is in the program, or the network latency or any other reason.

Don't blame the language before you've profiled your application carefully, maybe you have a bottleneck somewhere. The cost of a new development will be always very high, specially compared to a few line changes if you've found a problem in your code.

Answer (score 0):

how did you notice "slow performance" when using python? I mean, python is slow, ok, but for your use case it shouldn't matter. Did you profile the code? Can you paste the code here so we can take a look and maybe improve it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kind of performance issues you had with your program in python but it usually does great for me ( scripts parsing log files that are huge take really little time for instance...).
now It all depends on the general purpose of this. If its just a script, no gui etc.. then you should definitely look into optimizing python, or doing some perl or php-cli script.
I'm not familiar with it first hand but ruby seems to have a big following and seems very "internet" oriented aswel.

If you do want to create something more than a script you have lots of options, c# is one of them, but it won't be cross platform, i'd go with java.

In the end I'd recommend rechecking your python code, it seems odd that its not doing what you want performance wise.... python is really good.

Answer (score 0):

You should choose the language you feel most comfortable with. In most cases the performance of the scripting language is not the bottleneck. It is more important to get things done quickly and keep it maintainable. I would recommend you to choose Ruby or Python. If you have to get Python faster you still can choose to use JIT implementation like PyPy. Actually quite high traffic webapps, like YouTube, use Python.

Answer (score -1):

I'd go with the good, old PHP! It has proven time and time again, that it is more than capable of doing this, and is quite easy to learn.

So my advice: **Go with PHP!**